# Samba 3.3 or later on Slackware 12 - how do I make this happen?

Tags: linux, samba, slackware

I'm trying to upgrade the Samba server on a Slackware 12 box to serve as PDC for Windows 7 32bit machines (it now has a 3.0.3 and does the job for Win XP machines, but 7 refuses to join the domain - I'm posting this after having tried a few dozen hacks on the windows registry).

I'm a newbie on Slackware (I usually dwell in Ubuntu) so I may be going about this the wrong way but this is what I've done so far:

The Samba wiki has a couple of hacks for the registry and also seems to suggest a version later than 3.3 (though not in so many words) http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7

Having scoured the net for later Samba binaries for Slackware 12 and gotten precisely nowhere, I decided that maybe I could compile the blessed thing. But I keep on getting compiler errors. I'm using this SlackBuild script http://ftp.twaren.net/Linux/slackware/slackware-current/source/n/samba/samba.SlackBuild

Is there a better way to make this happen? (without upgrading the base system? it has so many finely tuned things running that I don't want to mess with the rest of the setup).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build 3.4.6 without major problems, two changes to samba. SlackBuild:

@line 25  VERSION=${VERSION:-3.4.6}
@line 47  cd source3

then build it:

./samba.SlackBuild

The final package will have .tar.xz name, but it will be really a gzip file, so rename it and installpkg

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it didn't work on a virtual machine I have with Slackware 12, and I didn't want to try it on the actual server.


Having said that, it would be great to get a repository with Samba binaries for different versions of Slackware for the incompetent in compiling (like me, that is).
For now I'm using the old Samba as a standard file-server - skipping the domain-controller portion that doesn't work.